# Can filter "depth" be adjusted by mixing dry and wet signals?

Tags: filtering

Can filter "depth" be adjusted by mixing dry and wet signals?

I.e. can I simulate e.g. a +6dB bandshelf/peak filter at 1kHz by mixing in some of the dry unequalized signal and some of a wet signal that has been bandpass filtered at 1kHz and the filter has around the same shape as the bandshelf/peak.

Can it be theoretically the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the input to the output of a scaled 2nd-order bandpass IIR **will** get you the classic peak/cut EQ curve.

adding the input to the output of a scaled 1st-order LPF or HPF **will** get you a 1st-order low-shelf or high-shelf EQ.

adding the input to the output of a scaled 2nd-order LPF or HPF will get you a *particular* form of a 2nd-order low or high shelving EQ, but there are many others.  doing it this way will often leave an unintended null or lump in the frequency response.  if you want a symmetric (in log frequency) and perfectly monotonic gain vs. frequency curve, i might suggest referring to the [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).

Comment: So they are even constructed that way. Was not sure if there would exists some algos for bandshelf/peak/cut that wouldn't be based on the bandpass (which itself is based on lpf and hpf). There are some peaks that arent "round" but more peaky though. Are those based on the bandpass as well? Like this http://www.delamar.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/equalizer_tutorial_01_peak_eq.jpg

Comment: uhm, **if** it's 2nd-order there **is** no other analog algo than the Massenburg sum of wire plus BPF.  there **are** different ways to map that 2nd-order H(s) to a 2nd-order H(z).  but they can all be divided into a *wire* + *something*.   so i would say that it's limited to that.  so it's similar to the 2nd-order shelving, there are different shapes that can result, but you can adjust the dB "depth" by mixing the dry input into the relative-scaled output of LPF, BPF, HPF to get low-shelf, bell, and high-shelf EQ.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the phase delays between the dry and wet path at every frequency in both passbands don't match, you can get partial cancellations or notches in the frequency response curve that you wouldn't get with a unified filter design.  So, to do this mix without that distortion, you might want a linear phase wet filter matched with an identical delay in the dry path before the mixer.

Comment: within the 2nd-order IIR context (so linear phase ain't necessarily there) you won't get a total phase cancellation with a BPF in a peak/cut filter.  you might with the 2nd-order LPF or HPF.  there could be a nasty dip, but at a frequency known in the design.